# an anchor link in bootstrap tooltip`s title doesn`t act like an anchor on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I am using bootstrap tooltip to add some info to an SVG path. I added an anchor link to tooltip's title and it's OK until I click on the anchor to do something. It doesn't act like an anchor, and does not raise any events.

This is the code:

```
<g id="B2" class="blockgroup">
   <path id="B2_Block" class="block" d="M195.4,128.9c-28,18.2-51.9,42.2-70.1,70.2l33.3,19.3c14.8-22.6,34-42,56.5-57L195.4,128.9z"/>
   <text id="B2_Text" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 166.0186 177.8625)" class="text">B2</text>
</g>

$('.blockgroup').tooltip({
            html: true,
            animation: true,
            container:'body',
            trigger: 'click',
            title: function(){
                return '<div class="tooltip-box">' +
                            '<span>Block</span>' +
                            '<h3>' + this.id + '</h3>' +
                            '<a href="#" class="view-seats" data-block-id="' + this.id + '">View Seats</a>' +
                        '</div>';
            }

        });


$('.view-seats').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you initialize click handler `.view-seats` element hasn't been added to DOM yet. This element is added to DOM after tooltp is shown. This should work:

```
$(document).on('click', '.view-seats', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('clicked');
})
```

Comment: Yup! it helped. Thanks